# Confusion with Sufficient Statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

reading from the first example of https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/283/ ([image])

where the likelihood of poisson can be factored into two components Phi(T(x),theta) and h(x1...xn) then T(x) is said to be sufficient.

However I don't understand that to compute the actual likely hood won't be have to compute h(x1...xn) also which does require knowledge of the individual values. So how have we reduced the problem? I understand the case where summation of xi is sufficient for multiple Bernoulli as h(x1...xn)=1 so indeed no knowledge of the individual values is required but can't get this one.

Comment: Reread the factorization theorem.

Comment: I have read it(-_-) and don't fully get it. To compute h(x1....xn) we need those individual values(as in the first example) so how have we exactly found something that is sufficient for those very values??

Comment: We are not bothered about 'computing' the function $h$; we only have to see whether we can find a $h$ which is a function of the sample observations $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ such that the joint density can be factored as $$f_{\theta}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=g(\theta, t(x_1,\ldots,x_n))h(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$$ The factorization theorem then says that the statistic $T(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is sufficient for $\theta$. Of primary concern is the function $g$ which gives us a sufficient statistic; $g$ depends on $\theta$ and on $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ through $t$.

Comment: Then what is the point? The point of a sufficient statistic is that instead of knowing and collecting every individual observation, I can instead just collect this one number like Sigma(xi) and it is as good for estimating my unknown parameter.

Comment: Where is the contradiction to what you said?

Comment: I said "To compute h(x1....xn) we need those individual values", you said "We are not bothered about 'computing' the function h we only have to see whether we can find a h which is a function of the sample observations  " . Why aren't we interested in computing the function? If we want the likelihood we have to right.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the factor $h(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ doesn't depend on the parameter(s) and is thus irrelevant for your knowledge about them. For instance, if you add two Poisson variables with the same rate parameter $\lambda$, you're twice as likely to get $1$ and $1$ than to get $2$ and $0$; but this factor $2$ is the same for any $\lambda$, so remembering whether you got $1$ and $1$ or $2$ and $0$ doesn't help you in estimating $\lambda$. For instance, if you have a prior $p(\lambda)$ and obtain data $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, the posterior distribution is

$$
p(\lambda\mid x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\frac{p(x_1,\ldots,x_n\mid\lambda)p(\lambda)}{\int\mathrm d\lambda p(x_1,\ldots,x_n\mid\lambda)p(\lambda)}\;,
$$

and the factor $h(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ cancels.